# Yahoo mail replacing inline width with min-width

Tags: css, html-email, newsletter, yahoo-mail

In the last days we have seen how our newsletters doesn't print as they use to do in Yahoo Mail. Some `<td>` elements are taking more space that they were supposed to take. After some checking we have seen that `width` attributes in our inline styles are replaced by `min-width`.

I was try to see if there were any change in Yahoo Mail but I couldn't find anything. The only thing I have found an issue in github explaining how this behaviour is suppose to happen in Yahoo and in Gmail with the `height`. I've checked Gmail and it's not happening and everything was ok last week in Yahoo Mail.

Is anyone suffering the same issue? Does anyone know the explanation to that?

[This is one of the newsletters](http://www.splio4.com/mr/6i45GwGCw/1303833/1235361107.html) suffering the problem, and [this is how we see it now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iAdiJ.jpg).

Comment: I think the `<table>` layout caused the issue. Have you tried using `<div>` layouts instead?

Comment: Not really, because it used to work like that. Seems that another one has asked the same and he got [an interesting answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37686026/6256093).

Thank you very much for your suggestion anyway, @AkhileshBChandran.

Comment: **Update:** Yahoo have fixed their bug, so this issue should no longer exist!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[I answered this question earlier today](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37683940/yahoo-changes-width-to-min-width-on-td/37686026#37686026), here's that answer:

---

Quick fix, place this in your `<style>` tag: **`@media yahoo {min-width:0!important}`**

This change/bug is brand new at the time of this posting. Yahoo is now changing width to min-width, breaking hybrid layouts among other things. There is a good discussion about other hacks in [the Litmus Community](https://litmus.com/community/discussions/5336-yahoo-mail-update-potentially-breaks-hybrid-emails).

Answer (score 0):

- Table elements for my purpose are parent elements to a button.
- For (parent) table elements  I placed "!important" next to "min-width" with no spaces.
- The html is placed "inline".  See the example below:

```html
<table align="center" width="200px" bgcolor="#0076be" style="border-spacing:0;Margin:0 auto;width:95%;max-width:200px; min-width:0%!important;">
```

- Button element has no inline style element of "width".
- See example below:

```html
<a href="[[asset_1]]" style="color: #fff;text-decoration: underline;"><img src="[[asset_3]]" width="195px" style="border-width:0;max-width: 195px; height:auto;display:block;margin:0 auto;" border="0" alt="Click Show Images to Make Links Work"></a>
```

Visit [Yahoo Mail Update Potentially Breaks Hybrid Emails](https://litmus.com/community/discussions/5336-yahoo-mail-update-potentially-breaks-hybrid-emails) for more information.