# Yahoo changes width to min-width on td

Tags: html, css, html-email, yahoo-mail

Sorry, not 100% certain if this belongs here or Super-User group but...

I have an html email, with 4 icons that I want centered and slightly spaced.

So, I have a table with 4 set width cells and an extra empty one on either side.

```
<table style="width:100%;border-collapse:collapse;table-layout:fixed;">
    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td style="width:32px;padding:0 4px;"><a><img src="" /></a></td>
        <td style="width:32px;padding:0 4px;"><a><img src="" /></a></td>
        <td style="width:32px;padding:0 4px;"><a><img src="" /></a></td>
        <td style="width:32px;padding:0 4px;"><a><img src="" /></a></td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Works in every email client in every browser I've tested (mostly using Litmus) except for Yahoo.

Yahoo is replacing the "width" declaration with "min-width" across all browsers, which is breaking the layout.

I've tried adding `width:32px;min-width:32px;max-width:32px` but it has the same issue.

Any workarounds or explanations?

Comment: Some of the solutions [here](https://litmus.com/community/discussions/5336-yahoo-mail-update-potentially-breaks-hybrid-emails) may be of use to you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quick fix, place this in your `<style>` tag: **`@media yahoo {min-width:0!important}`**

This change/bug is brand new at the time of this posting. Yahoo is now changing width to min-width, breaking hybrid layouts among other things. There is a good discussion about other hacks in [the Litmus Community](https://litmus.com/community/discussions/5336-yahoo-mail-update-potentially-breaks-hybrid-emails).

Comment: **Update:** Yahoo have fixed their bug, so this issue should no longer exist!

Comment: Yeah, it is fixed for width, but currently still have a bug on height, it still pushes `height` into `min-height`

Answer (score 0):

I faced the similar problem with height. Yahoo email client automatically converted height to min-height.

As a fix to this problem, I added **height="300px"** as an attribute to the  tag.

This helped me to solve the issue.